After local heat treatment of VT22 alloy with SP15 wire, a region with increased microhardness (494 HV). What structure could be in this zone?"
I am investigating the weld overlay on VT22 alloy with SP15 wire. After local heat treatment (quenching at 900°C with a 5-minute hold and air cooling, followed by aging at 600°C for 20 minutes and air cooling), a region with uneven etching appeared in the heat-affected zone. The microhardness in this area is 494 HV, in the adjacent zone it is 420 HV, and it gradually decreases further away. Could someone explain what structure might form in the area with increased microhardness and what could be causing this?
